# Is it possible that Revise outputs something when compilation is over and coding NFS?

Tags: compilation, julia

I am using [Revise with NFS](https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/config/#Polling-and-NFS-mounted-code-directories:-JULIA_REVISE_POLL-1) on my lab servers.

Currently, to know if my code has been compiled, I have a test function `t()=2` and when I have finished to code, I change to some other insignificant value `t()=3`.

I then type:

```
julia> t()
3
```

If the value is `3` then my code has finished to compile, otherwise, it is `2` and Revise hasn't finished to compile.

You see this is quite inconvenient and I would like to know whether there is a way for Revise to tell me when it is done? Maybe printing something in the Julia console?
In C/C++, you know exactly when the code has finished to produce, for instance an executable `a.out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is not really a solution and rather a workaround. I just found a way to avoid coding on NFS as I finally find Revise very suitable for coding locally and also not convenient at all for coding NFS.

Answer (score 1):

Revise should block until it is done recompiling. So if you have a new prompt, it should be ready.

Comment: I think, I may explained badly. I have a function `t() = 2`. I do some coding (using Revise, and mounting, NFS). When I am done, I change `t()=3`. The way I know when Revise si done compiling is by calling `t()`. Sometimes it will return `2` and as soon it returns `3`, I know it is over compiling. But instead of randomly calling `t()`, I would like Revise to print something for me. I hope it is clearer

Comment: I think, the fact that I am using mounting and NFS is the main point in my struggles. I believe what you said would have been adequate if I was coding locally.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the problem is about when Revise *notices* the change, as notified by the filesystem, not about (re)compilation per se.